# while count <= len(input)

Tags: while-loop, counting

I'm a newbee on python.

content is a string of 58 characters, read from file,so it will change.
`print(len(content))` gives the result 58

```
count=0
while count <= len(content):
    print(count, len(content))
count += 1
```

This will result in a loop that counts count from 0 to 141, not to 58.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Be careful about indentation, as it is written you have an infinite loop. It is paramount in python. Try to post a MVCE. (add an example of your `content` variable.) Just making that effort I am sure you will find your problem yourself. Also don't hesitate to use a debugger (PyCharm)

Comment: This is the result when I print(content):                                                                                 0, 3, 2, "I'm standing beside the empty dancefloor.",1,10

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the indentation, but it was a typo. In original code it is where it sould be.

Comment: Ok, it seems to have something to do with the content of content...

Comment: With content = "0, 3, 2, \"I'm standing beside the empty dancefloor.\", 1, 10" I still can't reproduce the behavior. Consider editing your question.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your tries. Problem solved. It all had to do with an honest mistake. When I examine content after reding the file on disk (one line at the time) it does not become a list. It is a string. when I then do len(content) I get result 58, which is right. When I then try to use this , python does not understand it is 58. I guess it interpret my string the wrong way. Solution:                   content = content.split(",",6) . Then content[0], content[1] ....instead of using while at all.

Comment: The while was for getting out data, one by one, from the string count.Hope someone understand what I did and could learn from this too.

Comment: Hence the importance of writing a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think anyone can learn from a mistake unless they don't understand it clearly with an example that can be reproduced and toyed with. Once again, consider Editing your answer.